# What cartoon had a cloud city guarded by angels above a volcanic earth, and a devil-like monster?

Tags: story-identification

When I was a teenager , there was a sci-fi fantasy animation TV series about a floating city above the clouds that guarded by flying humans with white wings who look like angels.
In the other site there was a red monster with black wings and horns who looks like the devil and had a servant.

In this story earth looked like an active volcano, and there were a lot of rivers of magma. 
The city has a very old scientist who was in charge of keep the city floating.

Comment: Thank you for asking this.  It seems so familiar, but I can't put a name or an identifiable image to it.  I hope someone knows it.

Comment: When were you a teenager?

Comment: It been something like 14 years since I've started searching this TV series, i was 4 years old when i watched Dragon Flyz, so i don't have enough memories left in my brain so I can describe what Im searching for, but i knew deep down in my heart that show was one of the best animations TV series That I watched when i was a child.And today I decided to do another desperate research and i finally found it !
So thank you **DSaad** you was able to describe it perfectly and **Paul D. Waite** for your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Dragon FLyz - Series Poster]

Are you thinking of ["**Dragon Flyz**"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115159/)?

Here's an overview of the show:

> The year is 4180 AD. Our planet, completely devastated by a great
>   natural cataclysm, is covered by dark swamps and shaken by *violent
>   volcanic eruptions.*
>
> The last survivors of the human race have built a *flying city,
>   Airlandis*, and drift above the turmoil, in search of a region spared
>   by the destruction. But this will not be an easy quest...
>
> Dread Wing, a tyrannical mutant warrior, has proclaimed himself sole
>   ruler of the dying planet, and that includes the human's flying city
>   too! For the four Dragon Flyz - Z'neth, Summit, Apex and Peak and
>   their flying mounts - the Dragons - a bitter fight begins against
>   Dread's troops.

A description of the "wings" that enable them to fly:

> All the main characters, good or evil, ride dragon mounts into battle,
>   but *have the ability to fly short distances* themselves. The
>   Dragonators make use of a technology whereby *dragonfly-like wings
>   (known as "Exo-wings")* emerge from the back-plate of their armor;
>   whereas *Dread Wing and his minions the Dramen literally 'sprout'
>   membraneous wings from their shoulders*.

[image: dragon flyz - dread wing - pic 01] [image: dragon flyz - dread wing - pic 02]

More about the chief bad guy:

> Dread Wing is the chief antagonist of the story, established in a cave
>   complex known as "Warnado" but anxious to live in the sky. His Dragon,
>   Blackheart, is the only one seen capable of breathing fire.

And just for the heck of it, some trivia:

> Dragon Flyz was based on the Galoob toy line of the same name, which
>   featured action figures that could actually launch into the air and
>   float down, helicopter-style (similar to the same company’s Sky
>   Dancers toys). Like most other toy-related cartoons, this show’s
>   fortunes rose and fell with its plastic counterpart. When sales of the
>   Dragon Flyz figures didn’t meet expectations, the animated series was
>   cancelled, leaving fans with only 26 episodes of memories.

<sup>*~ Edited from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Flyz), [Dragon Flyz Wiki](http://dragonflyz.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Flyz_Wiki), [TooNaRifiC](http://www.toonarific.com/show.php?show_id=1082) and [The BIG CARTOON Database](http://www.bcdb.com/cartoon_story/89805-Le_jour_du_dragon.html)*</sup>